# Hover Effect Addon Class Using CSS Only

Tags: html, css, styling

I am trying to create a reusable hover effect class using only CSS. I am aware that this effect could be achieved in myriad ways if one is willing to use JS or additional markup, but that is not my intention.

At the core of my question, I have discovered that it appears one cannot use pseudo-selectors on pseudo-elements. This is frustrating, since I believe that with the stated functionality, the below snippet should suffice.

```css
.btn-hover-effect {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-hover-effect::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-hover-effect::before:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: `.btn-hover-effect:hover::before` is the way to go

Comment: Use .btn-hover-effect:hover ::before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover effect applies on the .btn-hover-effect button so you should link it first.

```
.btn-hover-effect:hover::before
```

The thing you did was targeting the pseudo element before hovered, which won't work.

Here's a working test snippet:

```css
.btn-hover-effect {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-hover-effect::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in;
}

.btn-hover-effect:hover::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-hover-effect">Hello World</button>
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try to remember that! I've been using SO for month and I've seen so many jsfiddle links that I thought this was the way to proceed. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Fiddles may accompany a stack snippet but they are not acceptable as standalone usage. You even recieve a warning in your editor when posting a fiddle link without stacksnippet.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised I didn't actually try that before posting this.